# MySql SELECT names from users WHERE name LIKE "$searchTerm" AND status <> 'blocked'

Tags: mysql, sql, web-applications, select

I need to make a Query like this.

```
MySql-> SELECT names from users_tb WHERE names LIKE "$searchTerm" AND status <> 'blocked'
```

So The Query should SELECT all ROWS with names that match the "Search term", but Skip ROWS where `"status='blocked'"`. Now the issue is that Once the **Like '%$searchTerm%'** is called, the Query returns even those users that are **'blocked'**. In other words, the **AND**  is completely ignored.

How could this be properly done?

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This should already work, are there any whitespaces or any other characters stored in the table along the word `blocked`?

Comment: try `SELECT names from users_tb WHERE names LIKE "$searchTerm" AND not status like '%blocked%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the Query could run without warning or error, as you didn't mention that. So the problem is logically.

Please try

"**SELECT names from users_tb WHERE names LIKE "$searchTerm" AND status = 'blocked'**"

IF it comes out the result of name match to searchTerm AND status = blocked,

The SQL

"**SELECT names from users_tb WHERE names LIKE "$searchTerm" AND status <> 'blocked**'" 
should work for name match to searchTerm AND status NOT EQUALS TO blocked.

If it still doesn't. would you mind looking into your db records see if they are correct.

Comment: THANKS all for the Answers..... It took me hours, but it only WORKED when I did it like:

    MySql-> SELECT names from users_tb WHERE (names LIKE "$searchTerm") AND (status <> 'blocked')

NOTICE the PARENTHESIS **'('** and **')'**....That's all I needed to do....

Something that small can make you Grow-Gray-Hair prematurely...

Hope that help someone about to BANG his HEAD on the Keyboard...

Comment: @ErickBest, Let me take a wild guess, the $searchTerm contains speical symbols that affected the result. You may print the $searchTerm string to check.

Comment: ..NOT NECESSARILY.... The Search term is any letter a user enters in the search box.. There are several user names... Ex: if a user enters 'A', then The QUERY should go to the users_tb and SELECT all 'names' WHERE names LIKE '%A%' **BUT NOT** the 'names' of 'users' whose status COLUMN = 'blocked'..... If you **_AaronJiang_** was a REGISTERED member, that Name should appear, but If He is 'blocked'...His Name SHOULD NOT appear...

Answer (score -2):

here u are using '<>' in your query that's why you are not getting correct answers. Use of '=' will give you the correct result of your query.

Comment: HAHAHA....That almost took me on the floor...(lol)....Thanks anyWay for the inPut

Comment: For one thing, '=' CAN NEVER BE PLACE where a '<>' is needed... Is like PLACING the Positive sign (+) where the Negative Sign (-) is needed.... Sorry if I didnt Explain the Question properly... but What I wanted was far beyond shifting From '<>' to '='.....